# MVC multiple collections of same parent entity

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Okay, since everyone on here was a big help last time, I've come back. The base premise is this:

A Person can have Responsibilities over other Persons.

I have defined entities like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Responsibility> Responsibilities { get; set; }
}

public class Responsibility
{
    public int ResponsibilityId { get; set; }
    public string ResponsibilityType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I add a Responsibility to a Person, they end up with Responsibility over themselves, even in People is empty when I add the Responsibility to the Person.

Also, if I add a Responsibility to Person A for Person B, then Person B shows up as having a Responsibility for Person A:

Person A - Responsibilities for Person A, Person B
Person B - Responsibilities for Person B, Person A

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE

This is my assignment to the DB

```
// 7. Responsability (Line Manager)
                List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

                people.Add(personB);

                var responsibility = new Responsibility() { Type = ResponsibilityType.LineManager, People = people };

                List<Responsibility> responsibilities = new List<Responsibility>();

                responsibilities.Add(responsibility);

                // 7.1 Assign to Person A
                personA.Responsibilities = responsibilities;

                db.SaveChanges();
```

Still results in PersonA having LineManger over PersonA and Person B and Person B having LineManager over PersonA and PersonB

LATEST UPDATE

Seems to be an issue when I call db.SaveChanges(), as it's entirely correct before that. :(

Comment: Think this is down to your Navigation properties on the entities.  Think of it like this: When you add a Responsibiliy to a Person, you can currently go from Person to Responsibility OR from Resposibility to Person.  A Person has a collection of responsibilities and a responsibility has a collection of people.  There is currently nothing to say that this is a different type of "People".  Add a PersonType (enum perhaps) and then amend your Navigation so you can go People->Resp->RespPeople.  This should work.

Comment: are you using POCO (plain old clr objects as listed) or Entity Framework?

Comment: Check your Id property and what value it gets from the DB.  My guess is that its either not being set (and therefore it's int default 0) or is being set the same for everything.

Comment: Could you post your code for creation of PersonA and PersonB?  What gets saved to the DB?

Comment: Any update on this?  Have you tried specifically setting the ID's for your Person's?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Hi - yes I did manage to get it working, although the answer eludes me now as to what I did, but think I had to change the model so that Responsibility didn't have a collection of Person, but of entity ResponsibleFor which included the Person. Looking back I think this needed updating in the context with a HasMany as this has worked with my custom RoleProvider and Roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POCO Version - works for me using your classes.
*Note: I only added List<> because I am lazy where ICollection<> would work just as well!*

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Responsibility> Responsibilities { get; set; }
}

public class Responsibility
{
    public int ResponsibilityId { get; set; }
    public string ResponsibilityType { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Person> People { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var m = new Person { PersonId = 1, Name = "Mr Manager"};
    var r1 = new Person { PersonId = 2, Name = "Mr ReportsToManager"};
    var r2 = new Person { PersonId = 3, Name = "Mrs ReportsToManager"};

    var resp = new Responsibility
    {
        ResponsibilityId = 1,
        ResponsibilityType = "Manages",
        People = new List<Person>() { r1, r2 }
    };

    m.Responsibilities = new List<Responsibility>() { resp };

    m.Responsibilities.First().People.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r.Name));

}

Mr ReportsToManager
Mrs ReportsToManager
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, still get two entries in the DB

Will post full code below

Comment: Updated main item. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: No worries :)  Everyone here has helped me, we're glad to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Using EF4, just very slightly different, but same result.

[image: EF Diagram]

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Mr Manager"};

        var r1 = new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Mr ReportsToManager"};
        var r2 = new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Mrs ReportsToManager"};

        var resp = new Responsibility
        {
            Id = 1,
            ResponsibilityType = "Manages",
        };
        resp.People.Add(r1);
        resp.People.Add(r2);

        m.Responsibilities.Add(resp);

        m.Responsibilities.First().People.ToList().ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r.Name));

    }

Mr ReportsToManager
Mrs ReportsToManager
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your entity's Id properties - they should be similar to this.

You'll also want to check what the Db has set for the column.  Make it a primary key and identity column.

Check after calling the save that you actually have 3 people, and use SQL to get the same entity relationship.

[image: Id Properties]

Comment: Can I do this on a POCO model?

Comment: If its POCO then check your DB to see what is set and what the PK/FK's are set to.